# Storage Access Framework - set last modified date of local DocumentFile

Tags: android, storage-access-framework, documentfile

I want to copy or move files from the internal storage to the sd card. I do this via the Storage Access Framework (SAF) and the `DocumentFile` class...

Copying is stream based and the `DocumentFile` does not have a function like the `File` class to set the last modified date.

I know, that I move/copy files to the sd card, so I know that I create a local file. With this information, is it somehow possible to update the last modified date of the underlying file of the `DocumentFile`?

*It seems like you can't move/copy files from your internel storage to the sd card without losing the last modified date...*

**Reading - Working**

```
public long lastModified(DocumentFile file, Context context)
{
    long lastModified = 0;
    final Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(file.getUri(), null, null, null, null);
    try
    {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst())
            lastModified = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_LAST_MODIFIED));
    }
    finally
    {
        cursor.close();
    }

    return lastModified;
}
```

**WRITING - NOT WORKING**

```
public boolean setLastModified(DocumentFile file, Context context, long time)
{
    ContentValues updateValues = new ContentValues();
    updateValues.put(DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_LAST_MODIFIED, time);
    int updated = context.getContentResolver().update(file.getUri(), updateValues, null, null);
    return updated == 1;
}
```

This fails with a `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Update not supported` exception...

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't have an answer for you, however I'm interested on how to move and copy files using the Storage Access Framework. Can you help me or do you have a link to a tutorial?

Comment: The way I do it is via streams. Moving is copying + deleting (renaming only works if the folder did not change). You can check my UNDOCUMENTED library if you want to: https://github.com/MFlisar/StorageManager/blob/master/lib/src/main/java/com/michaelflisar/storagemanager/StorageManager.java. Check the `initDefaultHandlers` there, it shows how to copy/move files with my wrapper classes...

Answer (score -2):

Probably you need permission "android.permission.WRITE_USER_DICTIONARY" in manifest

Answer (score -2):

Since  API >=26 you can use refresh. This should work to update the Documentfile instantly . This works for me:

```
 context.getContentResolver().refresh(file.getUri(), null, null, null);
```